# sddm not starting after upgrade to 16.04, gnome and kde both installed

Tags: gnome, upgrade, kde, vmware-tools, sddm

I upgraded a VM Ware virtual machine from 15.10 to 16.04.
Services are up but the desktop is not, and the log messages are not very helpful. 
I am not sure if it's related to sddm settings, xorg, or vmware. 
I had some issues after installing some kde packages about a month prior to the upgrade. I went back to unity as my default desktop and that was working ok but i think sometimes I'd log in blindly on a blank window.

Comment: Have you tried switching to `lightdm`?  Use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to switch.  SDDM is old and being replaced.

Comment: i will try that now.

Comment: I tried setting that as default and rebooting and that did not work but I did get lighdm to launch manually from the cli which is more than i could do with sddm! Answer with try using lightdm and i will mark solved. I am fascinated to know what's wrong with sddm but more motivated by pressing tasks.

Comment: Thank you.  Also try disabling SDDM using the commands in my answer.  You can also uninstall it completely, which you might as well do if it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your default DM to `lightdm` by using this command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

You will be presented with a option box.  Choose `lightdm`, press TAB to select the OK button, and press enter.

You can also disable and uninstall SDDM by using these two commands:

`systemctl disable sddm`

`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove sddm`

Reboot when finished.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the sddm start issue after upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. From `/etc/syslog`:

```
chdir( /var/lib/sddm ) failed for user: "sddm"
```

`/var/lib/sddm` was not existing in my case. So, I created it and adapted its permissions:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/sddm
sudo chown -R sddm:sddm /var/lib/sddm
```

After that, "service sddm restart" made sddm working again.

I filed a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sddm/+bug/1431332 .

Comment: So this is unrelated to Gnome on top of Unity? I had a similar problem with 17.04 (virtual box guest). For that environment I started from a minimal install and added only Gnome and it works just fine where as installing Gnome after installing Unity caused similar problems to 16.04. Are Gnome packages attempting to reconfigure the display manager but do this incompletely and in doing so is removing that directory, yet leaving sddm ? (or this could be a similar problem but with the same result)